# Automate export of images from QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a project with a csv file of points (gateways, Image 1), a 3d surface model on top of OSM layer and a set of raster files (Image 2) which contain the information (in my case viewshed analysis results) and shown in two views, a flat one and a 3D one (Image 3)
Each VA-xxx layer corresponds to a feature on the "gateways.csv)

I am looking for a method to iterate through the "gateways" points, focus the map views on the point coordinates, and export to an image the result of the stacked layers (OSM, model and corresponding VA-xxx)

I tried with Atlas but I had no luck as I couldn't find a way to activate differen VA-xxx layers for different points of the gateways.csv

Is Atlas the right way? Is there any other way to execute such an iteration?

[image: Image 1: features of the gateways.csv file which should be iterated]

**Image 1:** features of the gateways.csv file which should be iterated

[image: Image 2: Open layers structure]

**Image 2:** Open layers structure

[image: Image 3: Desired view result to be printed]

**Image 3:** Desired view result to be printed

Comment: Is there any attributed connection between the raster layers and the viewpoints? Or do you "just know"?

Comment: @Erik I know. In fact, the VA-xxx rasters are produced with an interation of the `gateways.csv` so I have full control of the naming if needed, or I can maybe produce a new column on the csv to "link" to those files. i just have no idea which route to take :-)

Comment: create a bounding box and use Atlas to loop though that - we do this for 1000's of maps/images every month. we used this https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html as the basic starting point and modified for our requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz, I have already gone through this tutorial. The problem is I need different rasters to be rendered for each feature. For example, when atlas iterates through Serres_001, the visible rasters on the map should be OpenStreetMap, model and VA-001. The when Atlas iterates rthrough Serres_002, the visible rasters should be OSM, model and VA-002 etc

Comment: So the names of the layers are "linked" to each other, that should be a starting point.